# .net core AsyncLocal loses context with System.Reactive

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, executioncontext, callcontext

I want to use AsyncLocal to pass information through async workflows for tracing purpose. Now i faced a problem with RX.
Thios is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class RxTest
{
    private readonly Subject<int> test = new Subject<int>();

    private readonly AsyncLocal<int> asyncContext = new AsyncLocal<int>();

    public void Test()
    {
        this.test
             // .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Subscribe(this.OnNextNormal);
        this.test
             // .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
            .Subscribe(this.OnNextDelayed);

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                this.asyncContext.Value = index;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Main\t\t{index} (Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): AsyncLocal.Value => {this.asyncContext.Value}");
                this.test.OnNext(index);
            });
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void OnNextNormal(int obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"OnNextNormal\t{obj} (Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): AsyncLocal.Value => {this.asyncContext.Value}");
    }

    private void OnNextDelayed(int obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"OnNextDelayed\t{obj} (Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): AsyncLocal.Value => {this.asyncContext.Value}");
    }
}
```

Output is:

> Main            0 (Thread: 5): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   Main            1 (Thread: 6): AsyncLocal.Value => 1
>   OnNextNormal    0 (Thread: 5): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   OnNextNormal    1 (Thread: 6): AsyncLocal.Value => 1
>   OnNextDelayed   0 (Thread: 4): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   OnNextDelayed   1 (Thread: 4): AsyncLocal.Value => 0

As you can see, the AsyncLocal.Value does not flow to the delayed subscribed methods.
**=> AsyncValue gets lost on delayed track**

As far as I understand, a normal Subscribe() uses no scheduler and a Delay() uses a scheduler.
When I use ObserveOn() for both calls the output for both are as following

> Main            0 (Thread: 5): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   Main            1 (Thread: 7): AsyncLocal.Value => 1
>   OnNextNormal    0 (Thread: 9): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   OnNextNormal    1 (Thread: 9): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   OnNextDelayed   0 (Thread: 4): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
>   OnNextDelayed   1 (Thread: 4): AsyncLocal.Value => 0

**=> AsyncValue gets lost on every track**

Is there a way how to let the ExecutionContext flow with RX?
I only found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b96c83a-13ec-4943-80ca-df01f94df683/executioncontext-does-not-flow-consistently-through-observables?forum=rx) but here is the problem the otherway arround. They solved the issue how the context of observer flows. I want to flow the context of the publisher.

What i want to achieve is this:

1. Message from "outside" comes to my service
2. Distribute message within service (RX)
3. When logging a message, format the log message with MessageId
4. I do not want to pass the message everwhere

Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: The default scheduler used for `this.test.Subscribe(this.OnNextNormal)` is `Scheduler.Immediate`. As soon as you introduce any form of concurrency you immediately change scheduler. I suspect that's what's causing `AsyncLocal<>` not to work. You need to find another solution unless you just deal with the simplest Rx queries.

Answer (score 0):

The free flowing execution context in Rx is what makes it great for most multi-threaded scenarios. You could enforce the thread context by getting around the scheduled methods like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> TaskPoolDelay<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(
            observer => observable.Subscribe(
                onNext: value => Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(_ => observer.OnNext(value)),
                onError: observer.OnError,
                onCompleted: observer.OnCompleted
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Output :

```
OnNextDelayed   2 (Thread: 6): AsyncLocal.Value => 2
OnNextDelayed   3 (Thread: 10): AsyncLocal.Value => 3
OnNextDelayed   1 (Thread: 7): AsyncLocal.Value => 1
OnNextDelayed   0 (Thread: 5): AsyncLocal.Value => 0
```

This does carry-forward the context, but it quickly gets complicated for larger queries. I'm not sure if implementing an `IScheduler` which preserves context when it notifies will work well. If message copying isn't too much overhead, that might be the best fit for Rx.